# What happens after an F# Async.RunSynchronously is cancelled?

Tags: f#

Given an fsharp program like:

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use cancel = new CancellationTokenSource ()
    Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun _ -> cancel.Cancel ())

    let sleep = async {
      try
        do! Async.Sleep 20_000
      finally
        printfn "Finished"
    }

    Async.RunSynchronously (sleep, cancellationToken = cancel.Token)

    printfn "done"
    0
```

when I press Ctrl+C after a few seconds, what should happen?

I was expecting it to print 'finished', then 'done', and then exit. Instead, it prints 'finished' then hangs.

(If I break in the debugger I can see the main thread is still at `FSharp.Core.dll!Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>`.)

What should I do instead to get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't hang for me. Instead, I see "Finished" (because the `finally` block runs when the sleep is interrupted) and then the process exits (because that's what Ctrl-C does [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecanceleventargs.cancel)).

To get the behavior you want, I had to do this instead:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use cancel = new CancellationTokenSource ()
    Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun args ->
        cancel.Cancel ()
        args.Cancel <- true)   // prevent Ctrl-C from terminating the process

    let sleep = async {
      do! Async.Sleep 20_000
    }

    try
      Async.RunSynchronously (sleep, cancellationToken = cancel.Token)
    with :? OperationCanceledException ->
      printfn "Finished"

    printfn "done"
    0
```

When I run this from Visual Studio and then hit Ctrl-C, I see:

```
Finished
done

C:\Users\brian\source\repos\FSharpConsole\FSharpConsole\bin\Debug\net7.0\FSharpConsole.exe (process 35072) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the `args.Cancel <- true` causes the OperationCanceledException to be raised and then the process terminates.

Without it, I too see 'finished' but then nothing else. (The process doesn't terminate, there's no unhandled exceptions printed in output.)